# Как получить координаты центра отображаемой Google-карты?

Tags: google-maps-api, карты

При загрузке страницы на карте после определения геолокации (html5) появляется маркер.

Задача: после того, как он появился, при перетягивании карты он должен постоянно быть в центре (т.е. карта перетаскивается, а этот маркер всё время остаётся в центре).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете вызвать: `map.getCenter()`это вернет вам объект содержаний Lon,Lat.

А вот так можно получить координаты по нажатию правой кнопки мыши:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Спасибо!С центром разобрался.... Теперт все-таки не получается сделать так чтобы именно этот первоначальный маркер оставался все-время в центре карты пока ее таскают туда-сюда... То он бегает за курсором, то они плодятся при перетаскивании... Эх-эх-эх...

Comment: @Александр заводите новый вопрос, показывайте код.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function(event) {
    var g = map.getCenter();

   $('#lat').html(g.lat());
    $('#long').html(g.lng());
    coords = new google.maps.LatLng(g.lat(), g.lng());

    marker.setPosition(g);
});
```

Вот так все работает!)))
Спасибо!

Comment: Все таки не добился нужного "волшебства"(((Создам новый вопрос...